# Lattice fir filter in C programming?

Tags: c, algorithm, filtering, signal-processing

I want implement lattice fir filter in C. my question is how to make a delay time (z-1). I've tried to compute the previous sample for each iteration, but with the M'th first samples i have a negatives values.

You can find the algorithm [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF2yl.png)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: In the linked algorithm, `gm[]` is populated by values from `gm_minus_1` and `gm_minus_2`. So a direct translation of the algorithm needs four arrays - `f[]`, `g[]`, `f_previous[]`, `g_previous[]`. It *might* be possible to squeeze the same effect out of two arrays, but you'd need to be very careful to demonstrate to yourself that this was safe.

Comment: PS "There is something wrong" is not good enough, and one of the reasons you're getting close votes.

Comment: thank you slim;
i don't know how to obtain the first value of g[] i mean the first delay of g[]

Comment: Since your code is from ARM DSP docs, why don't you check their code to see where did you fail?

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a pointer to `float`, `i` is a `short int`. You're assigning `p` to `i` in the loop conditional:

```
void LatticeFIR(…, float *p)
{
    short i;
    …
    for (i=1;i=p;i++)
```

Notihing of that actually makes sense. Your compiler should blast out tons of warnings if you do that.

**EDIT:** *Just to give you the idea, this is what `clang -Wall` has to say about it:*

```
x.c:4:14: warning: incompatible pointer to integer
conversion assigning to 'short' from 'float *' [-Wint-conversion]
    for(i=1;i=p;i++)
             ^~
x.c:4:14: warning: using the result of an assignment
as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    for(i=1;i=p;i++)
            ~^~
x.c:4:14: note: place parentheses around the assignment
to silence this warning
    for(i=1;i=p;i++)
             ^
            (  )
x.c:4:14: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into
an equality comparison
    for(i=1;i=p;i++)
             ^
             ==
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: thank you for your answers
I do not look for errors at the level of prototyping but rather the idea how to implement the program, in other words how to have the delay for g[]

Comment: @Midou As you are new to this community, you hopefully learnt something essential: Be carefully with your wording and the presented code (in questions as well as answers). There are a lot of members which are very critical about this. (I guess, that it's good behavior for a C/C++ developer to be very critical and nitpicking. Otherwise, you _never_ get something running...)